# jquery delete dynamically create line

Tags: jquery

I have a script that creates new lines dynamically. In that piece of code, it creates two table rows.

```
var $row = $('<tr class="item-row-desc"><td>line</td></tr><tr valign="top" class="item-row"><td width="30"><a class="delete" title="Remove row"><img src="Images/x.png" width="16" height="16" /></a></td><td width="410"><input name="customFieldName" type="text" size="50" id="customFieldName" /><td width="130" align="center"><label for="agent"></label><input type="text" name="agent" id="agent" value="N/A"/> </td></td><td align="center"><input name="customFieldOurCost" type="text"/></td><td width="130" align="center"><input name="customFieldQuantity" type="text" size="10" class="qty" id="customFieldQuantity" /></td><td width="130" align="center"><input name="customFieldPrice" class="cost" type="text" size="10" id="customFieldPrice" /></td><td width="130" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="GST" checked="checked" class="gst" /></td><td width="130" align="center"><span class="exprice">$00.00</span></td><td width="130" align="center"><span class="incprice">$00.00</span></td></tr>').insertAfter(".item-row:last");
```

However, when I click on the 'Delete Row' button (it is in the tr), I want both s to disappear. I can only make the second tr disappear. Why isn't the first tr not coming of?

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
                    $(this).parents('.item-row').remove();
                    $(this).parents('.item-row-desc').remove();
                    update_total();
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('.item-row');
    $tr.prev('.item-row-desc').remove();
    $tr.remove();
    update_total();
});
```

The delete button is in `item-row` element, and the other row is the previous sibling of the `item-row`.

So `parents('item-row-desc')` will not return anything. You need to find the the ancestor `item-row` then first delete the previous `item-row-desc` after that delete the `item-row`. If you delete `item-row` first then you won't be able to find the previous `item-row-desc` element.